# how to specify extension for word file and text file in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i want to give extensions for word file and text file as `.doc` and `.txt` in web.config file.
 where in web.config should i write and what is the best practice. I am new to .net please Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your config file:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="FileExtension" value="docx"/>
</appSettings>
```

Then, you can read it the following way:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig1 =
    System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);
            if (rootWebConfig1.AppSettings.Settings.Count > 0)
            {
                System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationElement customSetting = 
                    rootWebConfig1.AppSettings.Settings["customsetting1"];
                if (customSetting != null)
                    Console.WriteLine("customsetting1 application string = \"{0}\"", 
                        customSetting.Value);
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("No customsetting1 application string");
            }
```

---

Refer to the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610xe886.aspx